# Styling checkbox without a label

Tags: html, css, checkbox

I tried [this](http://code.stephenmorley.org/html-and-css/styling-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/) tutorial to create a checkbox with a different style.

This checkbox has a label. When I delete the label it (or the text in it) the checkbox doesn't shown.

How can I see the checkbox without having a text?

Comment: In the CSS you can see everywhere `input[type=checkbox]:not(old):checked + label`, so if you remove `label`, CSS will not be used. So either change your CSS, or leave label empty - `<label for="XYZ"></label>`.

Comment: Simply an empty `<label>` would do I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the CSS you can see everywhere `input[type=checkbox]:not(old):checked + label`, so if you remove `label`, CSS will not be used. So either change your CSS, or leave label empty - `<label for="XYZ"></label>`.

**EDIT**

So just add `min-width` and `height` property:

```
input[type=checkbox]:not(old) + label,
input[type=radio   ]:not(old) + label{
  height: 45px;
  min-width: 45px;
}
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/bvzrnhnk/2/)

Comment: Here's example from [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bvzrnhnk/) with empty label (it doesn't work). I tried also to remove the "+ label" from the css (and remove the label from html) but it doesn't work either

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use input only, you can also use `apperance` property for styling checkbox. However it doesn't work on IE.

```
input[type="checkbox"] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  box-sizing: borer-box;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: url(//dummyimage.com/100x30/000/ffffff&text=click+me);
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked {
  background: url(//dummyimage.com/100x30/0e7d0e/ffffff&text=checked);
}
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/j9qbf8xh/1/)